# Convert csv to ical using Google Apps Script

Tags: csv, google-apps-script, icalendar

This should be easy and pretty standard, but I haven't found it anywhere.

So there is this webpage with lots of events I'd like to have on my gCal. But I don't want to simply import them once, as they are routinely updated, but rather to subscribe to an ical feed based on them.

So I've successfully parsed the page into a gSheet using the `IMPORTXML` function, and published it as csv, using the very same headers and formatting gCal demands for importing csv files.

Now all I need to do is convert csv to ical, since gCal imports but doesn't subscribe to csv (why?!). There are a bunch of csv-to-ical converters out there, and some even online, but they ***all*** require you to upload the csv file, rather than taking an url (let alone as an argument, rather than as a POST query).

If only there was a Google Apps Script to do it… is that possible? How?

---

So I wrote one, which is generating the ics file, which seems to be in order, as I formatted the fields in gSheets accordingly, but gCal, while taking the subscription without error, shows no events. I suspect it may be a related problem to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50789445/553579).

**csv2ical.gs**:

```
function doGet() {
  return 
    ContentService
    .createTextOutput(HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('template')
    .evaluate().getContent()).setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.ICAL);
}
```

**template.html**

```
<? var url = 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vQevL9qR46RxyhcmHrp8ekoElMLctUjazcuYlKsIkFeRsEQe0XOiYrJSF1OIyfRfshzUGncfdh12kst/pub?gid=709766031&single=true&output=csv'; ?>

BEGIN:VCALENDAR
VERSION:2.0

<? var events = Utilities.parseCsv(UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getContentText()); ?>
<? for(var i=1;i<events.length;i++){ ?>

BEGIN:VEVENT 
SUBJECT:<?= events[i][0] ?> 
DESCRIPTION:<?= events[i][1] ?> 
DTSTART:<?= events[i][2] ?> 
DTEND:<?= events[i][3] ?> 
LOCATION:<?= events[i][4] ?> 
STATUS:CONFIRMED 
END:VEVENT

<? } ?>

END:VCALENDAR
```

Comment: Is there a question here? Or is it just a request for people to finish the code you've started writing (which is off-topic here and better suited for someplace like GitHub)?

Comment: Ok, moved my partial answer to a separate answer.